# How to change which program is executed by default

Tags: path, executable

Surely this is an easy question, that I just don't know how to search for, but if I have two identically named executable files, one in */usr* and one in */usr/local* (for example), how can I change which one is executed by default without specifying the path, as in */usr/local/file*, if `$ which` returns */usr*?

Centos6.4 btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not always as simple as "which comes first in $PATH;" see https://superuser.com/questions/358695/how-does-linux-decide-which-executable-im-trying-to-run. For a quick fix, set an alias in .bashrc (assuming you're using bash...)

```
alias gorgonzola='usr/local/gorgonzola'
```

Note: white space is not allowed around the "=" sign.